# Better way of capturing multiple same tags?

Tags: python, html, for-loop, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to create an scraper which scrapes download links, I want to use regex but that would be a nightmare for me to do, I've found this library which is  called [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), I'm trying to capture the urls in the  children of `div class="article-content"` which is `<p>` tag, and this `<h3>` is the name of the urls,I don't want to combine all urls in one list but instead I used dictionary which is key is the name(`<h3>`) and value is the list of urls, enough of the talk here is the code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrape():
    resp = requests.get('https://www.animeout.xyz/love-live-nijigasaki-gakuen-school-idol-doukoukai-1080p-300mb720p-150mbepisode-1/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'html.parser')
    contents = soup.find('div',class_='article-content')
    output = {}
    for tag in contents.children:
        if tag.name == 'h3':
            name = tag.text
            links = []
            for sibling in tag.next_siblings:
                if sibling.name == 'p':
                    for link in sibling.find_all('a',text='Direct Download'):
                        links.append(link.get('href'))
                if sibling.name == 'h3':
                    output.update({name:links})
                    break
```

so far I only managed to capture only 1 key, is there a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Please change the title to something that can be useful to future users facing similar problems

Comment: No problem, I've edited the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this:

```py
import json
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def scrape(source_url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(source_url).text,
        'html.parser',
    )
    headers = [
        h.getText() for h in soup.find_all("h3") if "Direct" in h.getText()
    ]
    links = [
        anchor["href"] for anchor
        in soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name == "a" and "Direct" in t.text)
    ]
    return {
        header: [
            link for link in links
            if re.search(r"\d{3,4}p", header).group(0) in link
        ] for header in headers
    }


data = scrape("https://www.animeout.xyz/love-live-nijigasaki-gakuen-school-idol-doukoukai-1080p-300mb720p-150mbepisode-1/")

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

The reason you have one key only is that keys *have* to be unique but the names of the links are not. Change this with something unique, for example, an index number or the series title with the resolution.

Sample output:

```
{
  "Love Live! Nijigasaki Gakuen School Idol Doukoukai (main) Direct Download Links (300MB \u2013 1080p)(Encoded)": [
    "http://nimbus.animeout.com/series/00RAPIDBOT/Love Live Nijigasaki Gakuen School Idol Doukoukai/[AnimeOut] Love Live Nijigasaki Gakuen School Idol Doukoukai - 01 [1080pp][1080pp][Erai-raws][RapidBot].mkv",
    "http://nimbus.animeout.com/series/00RAPIDBOT/Love Live Nijigasaki Gakuen School Idol Doukoukai/[AnimeOut] Love Live Nijigasaki Gakuen School Idol Doukoukai - 01 [v2][1080pp][1080pp][Erai-raws][RapidBot].mkv",
    "http://nimbus.animeout.com/series/00RAPIDBOT/Love Live Nijigasaki Gakuen School Idol Doukoukai/[AnimeOut] Love Live Nijigasaki Gakuen School Idol Doukoukai - 01 [1080pp][1080pp][Erai-raws][RapidBot].mkv",

and so on ...
```

Comment: appreciate your effort for answering my question +1 for that, I did think about this approach, but its not actually limit to this, what I'm really trying to do is store those urls in values ex. `{'baduker':['https://stackoverflow.com/users/6106791/baduker','https://https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/163501/baduker']}` in a neat way.

Comment: I did think about that, but I was hesitant, as "Direct" might not be there, thus skipping it.